# peak to peak detection in android signal processing (audio)

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am trying to develop an app, which detects peak to peak value of a real time audio signal. Are there any in-built functions or API to perform peak - peak calculation in android?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think there is any such API for that, although you can use any of the many audio/digital signal processing libraries for Android like,

https://code.google.com/p/an-dsp/
https://code.google.com/p/musicg/

and you can google for more to see what suits your need.